# PHP - fopen() failed to open stream: permission denied Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, permissions, fopen

Good evening,

I am fairly new to PHP, right now I am getting permissions errors. I am using a Windows 10 enviroment with PHP, and composer installed. I am trying to pull files from an array of url's, but fopen gives me a permission error. Here is the code:

```
                        $fp = fopen($result['url'], 'r');
                        $out= fopen($filePath, 'w');

                        while ($buf = fread($fp, 5e+9)) {
                            fwrite($out, $buf);
                            usleep(500);
                        }
                        fclose($out);
                        fclose($fp);
                        $finished = true;
```

where $filePath is defined as 'D:\PST'. Is there any massive errors I am missing? D:\PST has full control permissions for the user group 'Everyone'. I am running the powershell window that I prompt PHP from in Administrator. I am using an Administrator account.

Thanks,

Answer (score -3):

Please follow link http://forums.iis.net/t/1167645.aspx

And check with this link http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/

Comment: Thanks, though I have already read the other thread. my fastcgi.impersonate is already set to 1, and as I said in my OP the folder has full permissions for everyone, so that shouldn't be a problem.